# USB soundcard works for audio test but not for mp3

Tags: pi-3, usb, audio, raspbian-jessie

I've been struggling to get my USB sound card to work with my Raspberry Pi 3.  After following some suggestions I have had limited success.  On startup if I run `speaker-test -c2 -twav` this test successfully plays off of my USB sound card.  However if I use `omxplayer -o local test.mp3` the sound only plays over the headphone jack.  The same thing happens in the GUI, if I double-click on an mp3 file, the sound comes out from the headphone jack only.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using alsa? I use it on RPi for playing mp3 over 1/8" jack, so not exactly what you're doing but I am playing mp3 so that's half your requirements.

If you check this article:

http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/01/sound-configuration-on-raspberry-pi-with-alsa/

you will see in the text and the first comment, the guy speaks of using alsa mixer to adjust volume through his USB sound card, so we know it has the ability. That would be the other half of your requirements if you can get it figured out. I don't have a USB sound card to try it myself.

Hope that helps.